# How use minimum number of commands to copy all .txt files from all subdirectories to one directory?

Tags: files, cp, file-copy

I have more than 90 subdirectories and inside each one, there will be a number of .txt files.

What I need to do is to copy all those txt files out to one single directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you seeking a minimal solution, or just something simple enough?

Comment: @richard the correct answer has given me what i need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use command :

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} /path/to/destination \;
```

Comment: +1 Be careful though because if two files have the same basename one will be overwritten. Also you can make it a bit faster by replacing `... \;` with `... +`, since cp accepts more than two arguments.

Comment: @user000001 …`-exec cp {} foo +` gives an error, it appears that the `{}` has to be at the end of the command. Do you need to do …`-exec cp -t foo {} +`

Comment: @richard You are right it gives an error. Note to self: Never comment before testing :)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid running one `cp` per file (as with `-exec cp {} /dest \;`):

```
find . -name '*.txt" -type f -exec sh -c '
  exec cp "$@" /path/to/destination' sh {} +
```

Or with GNU `cp`:

```
find . -name '*.txt" -type f -exec cp -t /path/to/destination {} +
```

With `zsh`:

```
cp ./**/*.txt(.) /path/to/destination
```

Or

```
cp ./**/*.txt(D.) /path/to/destination
```

If you want to include hidden files (or files in hidden dirs) like in the `find` solutions.